# Display single item from angularfire2 query

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

Is there any way to display a query from angularfire2 without using a ngFor loop?

```
this.user = this.af.database.list('items',{
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'id',
    equalTo: id
  }
})
```

I've tried outputting HTML with all these but only the loop works

```
{{user}}
{{user | async }}

{{user.name}}
{{user.name | async }}

<h1>{{ (user | async)?.name }}</h1>

<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let u of user  | async" >{{u.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

dataset is

```
{
  "items" : {
    "id-1" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "Gambit"
    },
    "id-2" : {
      "id" : 2,
      "name" : "Wolverine"
    }
  },
  "list" : "bob"
}
```

also debugging angularfire use to be simple by outputting json to the html, this doesn't seem to work in angularfire2, is there another was of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
this.user = this.af.database.list('items',{
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'id',
    equalTo: id
  }
}).map((items: Array<any>) => items.find(item => item.id === id))
```

But I would suggest to restructure your data, if you have `id` you should be able to get item directly:

```
this.user = this.af.database.object(`items/${id}`)
```

Check official docs: [Structure Your Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) for more details...

Answer (score 2):

Of course only the loop works since `.list()` returns a list as the name implies.

There is also an `.object()` method on AF2, which you could try.

To output json in your template you can use the json pipe:

```
users | async | json
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
singleObject = this.db.object('/items/' + id).valueChanges();
```

and then in html

```
{{singleObject | json}}
{{items.id-1}}
```